# How to create a xml file with specific structure using Php and Mysql?

Tags: php, xml-parsing, xml-formatting, xml

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $users = $xml->addChild('users');
        $users->addChild('Id',$row['sno']);
        $users->addChild('lat',$row['lat']);
        $users->addChild('long',$row['lng']);
        $users->addChild('address',$row['address']);
        }
$conn->close();   
//Create the XML file
    $fp = fopen("users100r.xml","wb");
//Write the XML nodes
    fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
    fclose($fp);
    echo $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

I want to create an XML file using the above code, but the problem is that it did not generate a required structure, which I actually needed.

I need an XML file with following structure. How can I generate it?

```
<users>
<point id="1" lat="24.24707031" lng="68.16540527" address="Pakistan"/>
<point id="2" lat="34.24707031" lng="63.16540527" address="Lahore"/>
<point id="3" lat="28.24707031" lng="55.16540527" address="Karachi"/>
</users>
```

Comment: Required xml structure is as:                                                             <users>                                                                                            <point id="1" lat="24.24707031" lng="68.16540527" address="Pakistan"/>                                                                       <point id="2" lat="34.24707031" lng="63.16540527" address="Lahore"/>                                                                               </users>

Answer (score 1):

If you want `users` as the root element, you will have to create the SimpleXMLElement that way. In the loop add the `point` element and set the attributes.

```
$rows = [
  ['id' => 1],
  ['id' => 2]
];

$users = new SimpleXMLElement('<users/>');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $point = $users->addChild('point');
  $point['id'] = $row['id'];
}

echo $users->asXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users><point id="1"/><point id="2"/></users>
```

If you want/need more control you will have to switch to DOM.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$users = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('users'));
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $point = $users->appendChild($dom->createElement('point'));
  $point->setAttribute('id', $row['id']);
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Or to XMLWriter, which is better for large files.

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI('php://output');
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->startElement('users');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $xml->startElement('point');
  $xml->writeAttribute('id', $row['id']);
  $xml->endElement();
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
```